# How to solve missing release file issue

Tags: 16.04, apt

I am currently trying to install syncthing by following the [official guide](https://apt.syncthing.net/) but after I

```
# Add the "stable" channel to my APT sources:
echo "deb https://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/syncthing.list
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following response

```
...
Ign:2 https://apt.syncthing.net syncthing InRelease
...
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://apt.syncthing.net syncthing Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Not sure how to proceed from here. Isn't there a 'secure way' to install scynthing? Has anyone had this problem? Help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you first need to add the syncthing release file.

Add the release PGP keys:

> curl -s https://syncthing.net/release-key.txt | sudo apt-key add -

Then add the "stable" channel to your APT sources:

> echo "deb https://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing stable" | sudo tee
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/syncthing.list

Now Update and install syncthing:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install syncthing`

[optionally] `sudo apt install syncthing-gtk`

Comment: I did add the release PGP keys but still getting the error.

Comment: is `apt-transport-https` installed?

Comment: `apt-transport-https is already the newest version (1.2.26)` @ptetteh227

Comment: clear your local repo `sudo apt clean` then do `sudo apt update` then install. Hopefully should fix it.

Comment: I cleared my local repo but `apt update` still does not find a release file. Tried variant `sudo apt install syncthing-gtk` and managed to install and ran the webUI but `apt update` still shows error `The repository 'https://apt.syncthing.net syncthing Release' does not have a Release file.` Is there a way I can verify the release PGP keys I get from the `curl -s ... | sudo apt-key -` command?

Comment: you can see if indeed the syncthing key is on your machine with `apt-key list`. then use curl -s `https://syncthing.net/release-key.txt > key.txt` to download the key and then compare the fingerprints

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75204/discussion-between-ptetteh227-and-natral).